# How to efficiently clear nested many to many relationship in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a code with models that have nested many to many relationship and I need to clear the relationship, however the solution I have is really slow, as it makes tons of sql queries.

The three models I have are Parent, Child, GrandChild. A parent can have many child and the Child has many Grandchild. 
What I need to do is remove the relationship of child and grandchild given the parent.

```
class Parent:
    children = models.ManyToManyField(Child)

class Child:
    pass

class GrandChild:
    # Can have many parents (aka. the child model) 
    parents = models.ManyToManyField(Child)

parent = models.Parent.objects.get(id=1)
children = parent.children.all()
for child in children:
    children.grandchild_set.clear()
```

This actually works and removes all the association of the child with grandchild for child associated with the parent we picked. However in my case there is usually over 5k child per parent, and each child has about 2 grandchildren. But this makes tons of sql query, and times out.

I am wondering if there is any efficient way to do this in bulk or by prefetching of some kind.

** Note: I only want the relationships to be cleared, don't want to delete the objects themselves.

Comment: Can you show the `Child` and `GrandChild` models (or at least the part where the relationship between the two is defined)? It makes a difference if it's one-to-many or many-to-many, and you question is a bit confusing on that part.

Comment: @EndreBoth I just made the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For M2M relationships, you can go through the intermediate table that you can access from any child instance (doesn't matter which) to get it done in just one query:

```
a_grandchild = GrandChild.objects.filter(child__parent=your_parent_id)[0]
a_grandchild.parents.through.objects.filter(child__parent=your_parent_id).delete()
```

You can also delete the relationships for more than one parent by passing a queryset of `Parent`s to the filter:

```
parents = Parent.object.filter(...)
GrandChild.objects.filter(child__parent=parents[0])[0] \
    .through.objects.filter(child__parent__in=parents).delete()
```

Comment: There could be many grandchildren though, not just one. I need to clear the child and grandchild relationship for all the grandchildren.

Comment: To reiterate, you delete the associations for all affected grandchildren, not just `a_grandchild` that you used to get a reference to the through table.

Comment: And this doesn't delete the object but removes just the relationship?

Comment: No, it doesn't delete any `Parent`, `Child` or `Grandchild`. It does delete rows, but it's the rows in the intermediate table that *represent* the relationships between `Child` and `Grandchild`.

Comment: Ok it works!! The only question now is it's a bit awkward to find `a_grandchild`. 
Just given the parent the conundrum is which `a_grandchild` do I choose to do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated with query to select a grandchild.

Comment: Just want to note that whenever you use `.through`, what you have on the left side is useless/extra/not needed. The `.through` property returns a class/manager. So, the `a_grandchild.parents.through.` is not actually returning that grandchild parents. It returns a `GrandChild_parents` class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `ForeignKey` on `GrandChild` and `Child` models, you can use something like this:

```
GrandChild.objects.filter(parent__parent__id=1).delete()
```

This will make chain join between the tables and issues one delete command to the SQL DB, instead of one command for each `child in children`.

**Edit: clear relationship**

If you want to clear the relationship of `grand_child.parent`, then do an `update`.

```
GrandChild.objects.filter(parent__parent__id=1).update(parent=None)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't want to delete the grandchild though, only want to clear the relationship.

Comment: Then you need to do an `.update(parent=None)` on it, instead of `delete()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have updated the questions to show the models. What I need to clear is not the parent, but the grandchild_parents in GrandChild model.

Comment: After updating your question, it seems you have M2M relationships, not One2M. The idea is the same and the implementation is somehow Endre Both wrote it.